# curl GET json request for more than 100 items

Tags: api, curl, get

I am trying to send a GET request for 300 items.
I am able to get 100 items with this request

```
curl --request GET --url "https://**/items?limit=100" --header "Content-Type:application/json" >test.json
```

with the following requests i am able to get 100 items for each page

```
curl --request GET --url "https://**/items?page=1&limit=100" --header "Content-Type:application/json" >test.json
curl --request GET --url "https://**/items?page=2&limit=100" --header "Content-Type:application/json" >test.json
curl --request GET --url "https://**/items?page=3&limit=100" --header "Content-Type:application/json" >test.json
```

Is there a solution to get all 300 items in one request and safe them in one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of the following:

1. curl --request GET --url "https://**/items?page={1,2,3}&limit=100" --header "Content-Type:application/json" >test.json
2. curl --request GET --url "https://**/items?page=[1-3]&limit=100" --header "Content-Type:application/json" >test.json

Comment: for both requests I get a error message
{
    "code": 422,
    "message": "\"[1-3]\" is not a valid page number."
}

Comment: I Just Tried and got the right response:
curl --request GET --url "https://www.google.com/items?page={1,2,3}&limit=100" --header "Content-Type:application/json" >test.json